# I used openMP directive on matmul function it does not work

Tags: c, openmp, openmpi

I am trying to use openMP in a `matmul` function, but it does not work...

In this part I tried everything, but it takes over 60 min to complete and it does not reduce any time.
What am I supposed to do?

```
int matmul( int l, int m, int n, float *A, float *B, float *C )
{
    int i, j, k;
    omp_set_dynamic(0); 
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(A,B,C) private(i, k, j) num_threads(4)
    for( i=0; i<l; i++ )                // Loop over the rows of A and C.
      for( k=0; k<n; k++ )              // Loop over the columns of B and C
      {
        // Initialize the output element for the inner
        // product of row i of A with column j of B
        C[i*n+k] = 0;       
        for( j=0; j<m; j++ )                // Loop over the columns of A and C
        {
          C[i*n+k] += A[i*m+j] * B[j*n+k];  // Compute the inner product
        }
      }
    }
}   // Added by edit!
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing details about the expected input/output of your code. What are you trying to achieve, and what does not work?

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question and added a closing `}` to your code. But your code is still O(n^3), so the runtime will be high, no matter what.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? How much time does the code need if you run it on a single thread and how much if you run it with 4? How did you compile it?

Comment: try `mpirun -bind-to none ...`

Comment: When you say does not work what do you mean? It works if it scales adding threads. Is it the case ? Moreover what is compiler optimization level do you use ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I dont see how mpirun options act on an openmp issue ?

Comment: @NPE try to run an hybrid MPI+OpenMP app with a recent Open MPI library and 2 MPI tasks. Then increase the number of OpenMP threads, and see what happens ...

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I don't understand. OP didn't mention hybrid app. And please tell me what will happen. A wasted process ?

Comment: @NPE as the author of the previous comment (who “dont see how ...”), I was simply suggesting you try a simple test that will hopefully shed some light.

Comment: @NPE the OP did use the openmpi tag, and that strongly suggests an hybrid app.

Comment: Swap the order of your j and k loop. That will be much faster. It's the simplest optimization you can do without doing register blocking.

Comment: What are the values of `l`, `m`, and `n` that take 60 minutes?  What optimization level did you use? What hardware are you testing on? What Compiler? What OS?

Answer (score 2):

> What am I supposed to do?

Use an optimized matmul from a [BLAS library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), rather than trying to write your own.

Optimizing matrix multiplication is non-trivial (you haven't considered vectorization or tiling yet, and both are needed to get high performance).

If you are on an Intel processor, [Intel Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl) is now free for anyone for any use and is highly optimized, or there are other implementations freely available.

I realize that reading a manual is less fun than writing code, but in this case it's also much more effective!

(In case it matters to anyone, I work for Intel, but this advice is entirely general :-))

Comment: I dont see why a new generation compiler can not produce highly optimized code for simple set of multiplication and addition operation.

Comment: @NPE Well, the intel compiler can replace your matmul loop with a call to MKL. Sure there is no hard boundary - a sufficiently clever could produce perfect matmul code. In practice, however, the disparity between complexity of the microarchitecture and cleverness of the compiler is huge. Matmul is a prime example because it is widely used. You can write a new thesis for every new architecture. [This short paper](www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith24/data/1965a144.pdf) gives a brief glimpse of the techniques that are involved.

Comment: This answer is certainly correct in practice - I feel it is a missed opportunity to learn more about writing correct and reasonable performing OpenMP programs. Unfortunately the question is missing critical details that would be required for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Zulan I dislike "use a library" answer especially on such simple math (in appearance). This is a trick question implying loop vectorization, intrisic function, memory alignment, cache, multi-threading on multi core, matrix multiplication cost (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm)… But ti's no reason not to give the key elements and surely I am not competent enough to do so (maybe Intel guys could…). As for compilers they do a pretty good job judging from the comparison between MKL and header only library like Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark

Comment: @NPE have you looked at the complexity of Eigen's implementation? It's irrelevant that it is header-only. Besides, eigen can use MKL or other BLAS libraries.

Comment: @Zulan I don't see why complexity is an issue. It's not irrelevant to be header only. How else would it accomplish lazy evaluation https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html, and take so much advantage of strong inlining. Yes Eigen can you use MKL be mostly for transcendant functions not basic matrix operation https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html

Comment: "mostly"? What do you think [that code](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/a09f8e033112ff88e67e7f8a12e524fcb2de2701/Eigen/src/Core/products/GeneralMatrixMatrix_BLAS.h) is doing? The whole point I'm arguing that in fact no current compiler can not produce highly optimized code for a *simple* matrix multiplication implementation.

Comment: on current architecture (read memory cache), code blocking is needed in order to achieve the best performances, and compilers are not there (yet).